# How to manipulate specific observations in a table, so that the observations are consistent when combining the tables using semi_join

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I want to combine two tables, using semi_join because table 2(`all_drafts_adj`) forms the basis to filter table 1(`draft_all_stats`).

```
draft_all_stats <- all_stats %>%
  semi_join(all_drafts_adj, by = "Player") %>%
  drop_na()
```

I noticed some discrepancies in the number of observations that do not match table 2 (`all_drafts_adj`)'s number of observations. The differences were due to the way specific "Player" was stated in table 2 vs. table 1 (e.g. table 2 "Player" was stated as "Dennis Smith" and the same Player in table 1 was stated as "Dennis Smith Jr".

I tried using the following R script, but it replaced all Player names instead of the specific observation:

```
all_stats$Player <- str_remove("Dennis Smith Jr", "Jr")
```

Most of the transform/mutate scripts are mostly targeted at entire columns or entire observations
Any on what R script to use to change specific observations with the data table?

Comment: # Hi xiuxiu, welcome to Stack Overflow. It will be much easier to help if you provide at least a sample of your data with `dput(all_drafts_adj)` or if your data is very large `dput(all_drafts_adj[1:30,])`. Please do the same for `all_stats`. You can edit your question and paste the output. You can surround it with three backticks (```) for better formatting. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the type Ian! Am learning on the fly. Appreciate the guidance and patience by the community :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the elements should be matched via partial match, then one option is `regex_semi_join` from `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
draft_all_stats <- all_stats %>%
     regex_semi_join(all_drafts_adj, by = "Player") %>%
     drop_na()
```

Or with  a distance approach with `stringdist`

```
draft_all_stats <- all_stats %>%
     stringdist_semi_join(all_drafts_adj, by = "Player") %>%
     drop_na()
```

Comment: Thanks akrun for introducing me to fuzzyjoin!